# Python - Split array into multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have a array contains file names like below:

```
['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png', '002_1.png','002_2.png', '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png', '003_4.png', ....]
```

I want to quickly group these files into multiple arrays like this:

```
[['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png'], ['002_1.png', '002_2.png'], ['003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png', '003_4.png'], ...]
```

Could anyone tell me how to do it in few lines in python?

Comment: In your desired output, should the third element be 001_3.png?

Comment: Is it always like this, I mean ordered ?

Comment: The third one should be 001_3.png, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
import itertools


mylist = [...]
[list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: x[:3])]
```

If input list isn't sorted, than use something like that:

```
import itertools


mylist = [...]
keyfunc = lambda x:x[:3]
mylist = sorted(mylist, key=keyfunc)
[list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=keyfunc)]
```

Answer (score 6):

If your data is already sorted by the file name, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
files = ['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png', '002_1.png','002_2.png',
        '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png']

import itertools

keyfunc = lambda filename: filename[:3]

# this creates an iterator that yields `(group, filenames)` tuples,
# but `filenames` is another iterator
grouper = itertools.groupby(files, keyfunc)

# to get the result as a nested list, we iterate over the grouper to
# discard the groups and turn the `filenames` iterators into lists
result = [list(files) for _, files in grouper]

print(list(result))
# [['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png'],
#  ['002_1.png', '002_2.png'],
#  ['003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png']]
```

---

Otherwise, you can base your code on [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086452/a-recipe-to-group-aggregate-data/50086453#50086453), which is more efficient than sorting the list and then using `groupby`.

- **Input:** Your input is a flat list, so use a regular ol' loop to iterate over it:

  ```
  for filename in files:
  ```
- **Group identifier:** The files are grouped by the first 3 letters:

  ```
  group = filename[:3]
  ```
- **Output:** The output should be a nested list rather than a dict, which can be done with

  ```
  result = list(groupdict.values())
  ```

Putting it together:

```
files = ['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png', '002_1.png','002_2.png',
        '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png']

import collections

groupdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for filename in files:
    group = filename[:3]
    groupdict[group].append(filename)

result = list(groupdict.values())

print(result)
# [['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png'],
#  ['002_1.png', '002_2.png'],
#  ['003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png']]
```

Read [the recipe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086452/a-recipe-to-group-aggregate-data/50086453#50086453) for more details.

Comment: Beatiful answer and upvote. I know the feeling when write a long and correct answer and nobody upvote it in order to recognize the invested time and effort into answering it.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Thanks :) I couldn't stand the low text/code ratio in this thread, so I decided to do something about it. Your answer was the only one that had a significant amount of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a `dictionary`.

```
list = ['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '003_3.png', '002_1.png', '002_2.png', '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png', '003_4.png']

dict = {}
for item in list:
  if item[:3] not in dict:
    dict[item[:3]] = []
  dict[item[:3]].append(item)
```

Then you have to sort the dictionary by key value.

```
dict = {k:v for k,v in sorted(dict.items())}
```

The last step is to use a `list` comprehension in order to achieve your requirement.

```
list = [v for k,v in dict.items()]
print(list)
```

Output

```
[['001_1.png', '001_2.png'], ['002_1.png', '002_2.png'], ['003_3.png', '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png', '003_4.png']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration and dictionary.

**Ex:**

```
l = ['001_1.png', ' 001_2.png', ' 003_3.png', ' 002_1.png', ' 002_2.png', ' 003_1.png', ' 003_2.png', ' 003_3.png', ' 003_4.png']
r = {}
for i in l:
    v = i.split("_")[0][-1]
    if v not in r:
        r[v] = []
    r[v].append(i)
print(r.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[['001_1.png', ' 001_2.png'], [' 003_3.png', ' 003_1.png', ' 003_2.png', ' 003_3.png', ' 003_4.png'], [' 002_1.png', ' 002_2.png']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is ordered like this here is a short script for this task.

```
myList = []
for i in a:
    if i[:-4].endswith('1'):
        myList.append([i])
    else:
        myList[-1].append(i)

# [['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '003_3.png'], ['002_1.png', '002_2.png'], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#IYN

mini_list = []
p = ['001_1.png', '001_2.png', '001_3.png', '002_1.png','002_2.png', '003_1.png', '003_2.png', '003_3.png', '003_4.png']
new_p = []

for index, element in enumerate(p):
    if index == len(p)-1:
        mini_list.append(element)
        new_p.append(mini_list)
        break

    if element[0:3]==p[index+1][0:3]:
        mini_list.append(element)

    else:
        mini_list.append(element)
        new_p.append(mini_list)
        mini_list = []

print (new_p)
```

The code above will cut the initial list into sub lists and append them as individual lists into a resulting, larger list.
Note: not a few lines, but you can convert this to a function.

```
def list_cutter(ls):
    mini_list = []
    new_list = []

    for index, element in enumerate(ls):
        if index == len(ls)-1:
            mini_list.append(element)
            new_list.append(mini_list)
            break

        if element[0:3]==ls[index+1][0:3]:
            mini_list.append(element)

        else:
            mini_list.append(element)
            new_list.append(mini_list)
            mini_list = []

    return new_list
```