# Get maximum tuples in list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples that can be understood as key-value pairs, where a key can appear several times, possibly with different values, for example

```
[(2,8),(5,10),(2,5),(3,4),(5,50)]
```

I now want to get a list of tuples with the highest value for each key, i.e.

```
[(2,8),(3,4),(5,50)]
```

The order of the keys is irrelevant.

How do I do that in an efficient way?

Comment: Use an intermediate dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort them and then cast to a dictionary and take the items again from it:

```
l = [(2,8),(5,10),(2,5),(3,4),(5,50)]
list(dict(sorted(l)).items()) #python3, if python2 list cast is not needed
[(2, 8), (3, 4), (5, 50)]
```

The idea is that the key-value pairs will get updated in ascending order when transforming to a dictionary filtering the lowest values for each key, then you just have to take it as tuples.

Comment: Just to be clear for myself, sorting a list beforehand and then casting it to a dict applies some kind of ordering ? Is it definite that every time this will give the same result ?

Comment: @BcK Constructing a dictionary from an iterable (like a list) inserts the items one after another, overwriting existing keys. If the iterable is sorted, only the maximum value for each key survives.

Comment: @BcK, it will give the same result in python3 because if i recall properly dictionaries assure to have the same ordering over keys, but not in python2. let me check about this.

Comment: The output of `items()` is probably not guaranteed to be the same each time. Otherwise there would be no need for `OrderedDict` to exist.

Comment: @BcK, from python3.6 they maintain insertion order, https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation. So they will be always ordered.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The overwriting part was really sightful. Thanks.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Does casting to a dict automatically eliminate duplicate keys? Edit: Just saw the explanation form @mkrieger1, thanks

Comment: @GittaGrün, it does, since in dicts you can only have single keys pairing

Comment: @Chris_Rands, actually you need it to be sorted that way, which is default tuple ordering, or at least by the "values", you want bigest of them the last ones

Comment: –1 The question asked "How do I do that in an efficient way?". Sorting introduces an inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

At its core, this problem is essentially about grouping the tuples based on their first element and then keeping only the maximum of each group.

Grouping can be done easily with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). A detailed explanation of grouping with defaultdicts can be found in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086452/a-recipe-to-group-aggregate-data/50086453#50086453). In your case, we group the tuples by their first element and then use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function to find the tuple with the largest number.

```
import collections

tuples = [(2,8),(5,10),(2,5),(3,4),(5,50)]

groupdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for tup in tuples:
    group = tup[0]
    groupdict[group].append(tup)

result = [max(group) for group in groupdict.values()]
# result: [(2, 8), (5, 50), (3, 4)]
```

In your particular case, we can optimize the code a little bit by storing only the maximum 2nd element in the dict, rather than storing a list of all tuples and finding the maximum at the end:

```
tuples = [(2,8),(5,10),(2,5),(3,4),(5,50)]

groupdict = {}
for tup in tuples:
    group, value = tup

    if group in groupdict:
        groupdict[group] = max(groupdict[group], value)
    else:
        groupdict[group] = value

result = [(group, value) for group, value in groupdict.items()]
```

This keeps the memory footprint to a minimum, but only works for tuples with exactly 2 elements.

---

This has a number of advantages over [Netwave's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251705/1222951):

- It's more readable. Anyone who sees a defaultdict being instantiated knows that it'll be used to group data, and the use of the `max` function makes it easy to understand which tuples are kept. Netwave's one-liner is clever, but clever solutions are rarely easy to read.
- Since the data doesn't have to be sorted, this runs in linear O(n) time instead of O(n log n).

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep running maximums in the dict instead of collecting all values and computing the maxes at the end.

Comment: Also, keeping tuples instead of just values in the groups requires that the keys support `key < key`. That works for int keys, but for non-comparable keys, it'd require adjustment.

Comment: @user2357112 Each solution has its own disadvantages, but I added a version with a running maximum. It's certainly worth showing, even if it only works with 2-tuples.